# Graph theory and trees questions

Tags: graph-theory, trees, random-graphs

[image]

**(a) Is false**.

If $G$ is a tree then: $|E|=|V|-1$

So, $|E|=9-1=8$. But because the sum of the degrees of all vertices is equal to $2|E|$, we have $2|8|=16\neq18$

**(b) Is true**

If $G$ is a graph then: $|E| \geq |V|-|W| $, where |W| is the number of connected parts of the graph.
We have $|E| \geq |V|-|W| $, so $|7| \geq 12-5=7$

**(c) Is false**.

$|E| \geq |V|-|W| $

So $24 \geq 30-5=25$ and this is false

> How do I prove that **(d),(e)** are false?

**EDIT**:

**(d) Is false**

If the graph is acyclic then it's a forest and we have $|E|=|V|-1$, so we should have $9=9-1=8$ which is impossible.

Comment: If the graph in (d) is acyclic, doesn't it have to be a tree or a forest? That should allow you to apply the formula you used in (a).

Comment: Can these graphs be multigraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if a graph $G$ is connected and $|E|=|V|+k$ then $G$ has atleast $k+1$ cycles.

In case of **(e)** we have $12=5+k \Leftrightarrow k=7$.

So $G$ has atleast $8$ cycles.

Conclusion: **(e)** is false because it says that $G$ has less than $8$ cycles.

Comment: The proposition I said can be proved by induction.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a subgraph of the (e) graph which is a tree. It has 4 edges. Then add missing 8 edges one-by-one. Every time you add an edge, it connects vertices which are already connected, so at least one simple cycle is added; so there are no less than 8 simple cycles in that graph.